# Find the roots for y

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, radical-equations

> $$-1=(0.55)\cdot[1+(y+1)^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

I got stuck with this expression. I have l some difficulty in leanding with some algebraic manipulation. What should I do to solve this equation??

I tried to answer but without results. I thought in taking square roots of booth sides, but this will lead me to the complex numbers.

Comment: Divide both sides by $0.55$.  Then raise both sides to the $2/3$'d power.  Note that a nonzero number raised to the $2/3$'d power can have three possible answers, at most one of which is real.  At this point the LHS is just a number and the RHS is just $1+(y+1)^2$.  Can you continue at this point on your own?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: All I was doing in what I suggested is "undoing the operations from the outside-in"... it wasn't all that fancy... just recognizing that to undo multiplication by $0.55$ requires division by $0.55$... that to undo raising to the power of $3/2$ is to raise to the power of $2/3$, and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep breath and be careful.

$-1= (0.55) \cdot[1 + (y+1)^2]^{\frac 32}$

$-1 = \frac {55}{100}\cdot[1 + (y+1)^2]^{\frac 32}$

$-\frac {100}{55} = -\frac {20}{11} = [1 + (y+1)^2]^{\frac 32}$

$(-\frac {20}{11})^{\frac 23} = 1 + (y+1)^2$

$(-\frac {20}{11})^{\frac 23} -1 = (y+1)^2$

$[(-\frac {20}{11})^{\frac 23} -1]^{\frac 12} =y +1$

$[(-\frac {20}{11})^{\frac 23} -1]^{\frac 12} -1 = y$

Now there are three values for $(-\frac {20}{11})^{\frac 23}$ (they are $\sqrt[3]{\frac {20}{11}}^2,\sqrt[3]{\frac {20}{11}}^2e^{\frac 23\pi i},\sqrt[3]{\frac {20}{11}}^2e^{\frac 43\pi}$).

ANd so there are six values for $[(-\frac {20}{11})^{\frac 23} -1]^{\frac 12} -1$